# How to Extract PaymentKeys from below response in Jmeter

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

```
{"PaymentKeys":["2d34b3b2-ae35-4778-965c-6eb71421f32f",
"82ba494b-7eb9-458a-914c-6542e73e0e22"],"Attributes":
[{"Key":"CardIssuer","Value":"Unknown"},
{"Key":"MaskedCardNumber","Value":null}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON extractor` from post-processors with proper json path: `$.PaymentKeys`.

Comment: Got it Thank You!!